# Select value from AJAX text box using Selenium WebDriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Can someone please suggest how to select the value from an AJAX text box using Selenium WebDriver Java API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by doing it *that* way :) ...

Answer (score 0):

You've given us no code at all to work with.

You need to look at this website: www.whathaveyoutried.com

Given a sample webpage like this:

```
<html
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="ageTextBox" >Please enter your age:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ageTextBox" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I could get the textbox and it's value like so:

```
WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.id("ageTextBox"));
query.getText(); // this will give you a string containing whats in the textbox
```

Note: You don't seem to have read any Selenium tutorials, as this is basic steps that are covered in these types of tutorials. Please look at the Selenium website & documentation.

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've indeed skimmed through the doc, but will read in detail (don't have much time due to project delivery). Are the ids reliable in general? What if my application doesn't have id defined for an element such as a table?

Comment: Also, do you suggest any other place where I can find documentation for Selenium cuz the doc on the Selenium website doesn't seem to cover all aspects of WebDriver based automation.

Comment: Which aspects are not covered? As for ID's, they are the quickest and most reliable way of finding elements, but of course there are other ways too. Again, it's explained on the Selenium documentation. A favourite is XPath selectors - this will get around the issue on tables. http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#locating-ui-elements-webelements

Answer (score 0):

If the id for the input field is `id="gs_htif0"`, and you want to read the data from the text field, you can use the below lines of code:

```
WebElement Text=driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).getAttribute("Placeholder");
System.out.println(Text);
```